# How to apply background colors to Kibana tables in the same dashboard (or not)

Tags: kibana, visualization, background-color, dashboard, elasticsearch-query

I have a challenge to implement colorized tables in a Kibana Dashboard and tried to find out the best approach in internet, but no glue up to now. So, since I wouldn't like to re-invent the wheels and create from scratch, I would like to hear from you an updated status for this implementation. By the way, I know that we can define a cell color based on its value, but it cannot be only the cell color, it must be all table lines or at least, one full line.

The challenge is to draw two simple tables in the same dashboard, one completely RED and a second all GREEN. Here is one table example:
[Report example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9aDt.jpg)

Have you have figured out some way to define the background color to the tables into a kibana dashboard, a kibana visualisation component or even by deployment level customization by HTML or CSS files customization?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the ways for solving this challenge. In order to figure out any additional formatting, I do suggest to use F12 in Chrome and debug some CSS statements.

1. CSS file to be changed:

- /usr/share/kibana/optimize/bundles/light-theme.style.css

2. Let's consider the following tables titles

- Table 1 title: "TOP_RED_TABLE"
- Table 2 title: "BOTTON_GREEN_TABLE"

2. At the end of CSS file, add the following lines (replace the table titles below according with your definitions into the dashboard)

   [data-title="TOP_RED_TABLE"],[data-test-subj="embeddablePanelHeading-TOP_RED_TABLE"] {
   background-color:red;
   color:white;
   }

   [data-title="BOTTON_GREEN_TABLE"], [data-test-subj="embeddablePanelHeading-BOTTON_GREEN_TABLE"] {
   background-color:green;
   color:white;
   }
   .table thead {
   font-size: 14px;
   background-color:black;
   color:white;
   }

   .embPanel__title:not(:empty) {
   font-size: 16px;
   }

Good luck with your kibana customizations and please, post here any additional suggestions.

Tks

Marcelo

Comment: Hi Marcelo, I did exactly like you recommended. But however, Kibana does not take these modifications into account. I modified /usr/share/kibana/optimize/bundles/light-theme.style.css, but when Kibana is loaded in Chrome, this exact stylesheet appears unchanged. So my modifications are not present in the light.theme.style.css file that is shown in "Elements" when inspecting. What am I doing wrong? I am on Kibana 7.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you clean up your browser cache according with steps below:
1 - Hit F12
2 - Select "Network" menu item
3 - Hit F5
4 - Hit mouse right button over the files names that will appear
5 - Select "Clear browser cache" option in the opened menu window

Additionally, I would suggest to review if you have properly named your

Comment: I would also suggest to review if you have properly renamed your panel title accordingly (for instance, to the name "TOP_RED_TABLE")

Finally, let me know if you are trying to create a component from Visualization or adding a simple Query Search (Dashboard > Add > Type=Search Query) into your dashboard panel. They are differently refered into CSS and these given CSS tags apply to "Seach Query" usage (a simple table). 

Let me know if you aim to use Data Tables and I will try to provide you other tags.